# Not able to checkout the source from Perforce Label through Jenkins shell

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, perforce

I am trying to checkout the source code from the specific Perforce Label/Change List through shell in the Jenkins project but I am facing the error while accessing perforce from Jenkins. Below is the code snippet

```
export P4USER=username
export P4PORT=test.port:1666 
export P4CLIENT=client_name

p4 label @LABEL_NAME
```

As per my understanding above code should check out the code from the specified perforce label but I am getting below error:

"Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset. Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure"

I have also tried to set the Password by below command but still I am getting the same above error.

```
export P4PASSWD=xxxxx
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Hemant

Comment: Does the exact same command work from a command line executed by the Jenkins user?

Comment: The `p4 label` command does not check out code; it modifies a label template and its description. Use `p4 sync` to check out code. But it sounds like your real problem is that you are not logged in to the Perforce server.

Comment: I was using the wrong command as bryan commented. As per my understanding,the correct command to checkout perforce label would be "_p4 sync //depot_path/...@label_". Brayan please correct me if I am still using the wrong command. I have tried the same steps from the command line also but I am getting the same error.